# How do I get the list of all CSS files?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to understand how I can have the whole list of the CSS, JavaScript,  and the others files declared with the libraries method (or added in any right way to Drupal).

Earth would be a better place with a function like `get_all_assets()`.

We are planning to create a less files aggregator and compiler ...

Comment: Not sure why you need to do this?  Drupal does a great job of aggregating and minimizing css and JS already.  And if you don't like the default method, there is the advance aggregation model that gives you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Assets are not generally/necessarily global. It would have to be `get_all_assets_in($some_request)`

Comment: With aggregation disabled all you need to do is to inspect your site's HTML source from inside your browser.

Comment: Also https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg already exists. Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: What are you talking about?
I need a way to get the whole tree of each asset of my Drupal 8 installation (into a structured way, for instance an array). I don't need to aggregate or optimize!
Do you know how to get the full tree of css, js, less files added to Drupal?
Thanks